# need help in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

hello guys i m new to loopback and i go through all document but haven't find any solution related to my problem as describe below
1. is it possible to change table name for eg:-

```
var mysqlDs = app.dataSources.mysqlDs;
function createCoffeeShops(cb) {
mysqlDs.automigrate('CoffeeShop', function(err) {
  if (err) return cb(err);
  var CoffeeShop = app.models.CoffeeShop;
  CoffeeShop.create([{
    name: 'Bel Cafe',
    city: 'Vancouver',
  }, {
    name: 'Three Bees Coffee House',
    city: 'San Mateo',
  }, {
    name: 'Caffe Artigiano',
    city: 'Vancouver',
  }], cb);
});
```

this code i found in official document of loopback.io and my model name is CoffeeShop now here is my question how i can automigrate with different table name of eg :- mysqlDs.automigrate('CoffeeShop'// i want this name as employee is this thing is not possible or i missing something
2.second thing how i can create controller for eg:- suppose my folder structure is like this

1.client
2.common
3.server
now i want to  create new folder name like controller and here i want to place my all business logic now   my question is that how i can link this file to my model and all other required file overall during execution this file should also execute is these thing possible in loopback

Comment: I use npm to automigrate with this code in package.json `"scripts": {  "init": "NODE_ENV=init node ."  }` it will create database tables corresponding to your model.json

Comment: also you can map your controller to your remoteMethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It looks like you are using MySQL. Apply the following to your `CoffeeShop` definition to use the table name `employee`.

   ```
   {
     "name": "CoffeeShop",
     "options": {
       "mysql": {
         "table": "employee"
       }
     },
     ...
   }
   ```

   This is documented in [Model definition JSON file](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#data-source-specific-options).
2. I'd recommend keeping with LoopBack's recommended directories until you gain more experience with the framework. If you really want to place models in a folder named `controller`, you'll want to look into the `server/model-config.json` file. At the top, you'll see a section for `_meta.sources`. You can add your new folder here and begin putting models in that folder.

   ```
   {
     "_meta": {
       "sources": [
         ...,
         "../controller"
       ]
     }
   }
   ```